# Dynamic quadrant label positions with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, label

I am creating a bubble chart with quadrant labels and want to move these positions as I zoom in. I was looking at the documentation but could not figure out. I would appreciate any help on this. Thanks!

Here is my code. [Link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ddjqspd/11/)

```
function segmentation(segData) {
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'segmentation',
      type: 'bubble',
      plotBorderWidth: 1,
      zoomType: 'xy',
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Title'
    },

    xAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 6,
      gridLineWidth: 1,
      title: {
        text: 'X Label'
      },
      labels: {
        format: '{value}'
      },
      plotLines: [{
        color: 'red',
        dashStyle: 'dot',
        width: 2,
        value: 3,
        label: {
          rotation: 0,
          y: 15,
          style: {
            fontStyle: 'italic',
            color: 'red',
          },
          text: 'Y HIgh'
        },
        zIndex: 3
      }, ]
    },

    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 6,
      startOnTick: false,
      endOnTick: false,
      title: {
        text: 'Y Label',
      },
      labels: {
        format: '{value}'
      },
      maxPadding: 0.2,
      plotLines: [{
        color: 'red',
        dashStyle: 'dot',
        width: 2,
        value: 3,
        label: {
          align: 'right',
          style: {
            fontStyle: 'italic',
            color: 'red',
          },
          text: 'X High',
          x: 5
        },
        zIndex: 3
      }]
    },
    tooltip: {
      useHTML: true,
      headerFormat: '<table>',
      pointFormat: '<tr><th colspan="2"><h4>{point.job_title}</h4></th></tr>' +
        '<tr><th>X :</th><td>{point.x:.2f}</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><th>X:</th><td>{point.y:.2f}</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><th>Count :</th><td>{point.z}</td></tr>',
      footerFormat: '</table>',
      followPointer: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: '{point.job_title}'
        }
      }
    },

    series: [{
      data: [{
        'name': 'D',
        'x': 4,
        'y': 4,
        'z': 40
      }, {
        'name': 'A',
        'x': 1,
        'y': 1.158,
        'z': 4
      }, {
        'name': 'C',
        'x': 1.2,
        'y': 0.304347826087,
        'z': 7
      }, {
        'name': 'B',
        'y': 0.0118577075099,
        'z': 3
      }]
    }]

  }, function(chart) {
    chart.renderer.text('Quadrant B', 150, 290).css({
      color: '#929195',
      fontSize: '60px',
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    }).add();
    chart.renderer.text('Quadrant A', 600, 290).css({
      color: '#929195',
      fontSize: '60px',
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    }).add();
    chart.renderer.text('Quadrant C', 150, 735).css({
      color: '#929195',
      fontSize: '60px',
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    }).add();
    chart.renderer.text('Quadrant D', 600, 735).css({
      color: '#929195',
      fontSize: '60px',
      fontWeight: 'bold'
    }).add();
  });
};
```

1) Before Zoom
[image]

2) Zooming into Quadrant C
[image]

3) Want to see only "Quadrant C" but all the quadrant labels show up
[image]

Comment: You could save your custom labels into some chart's properties and after a setExtremes event of an xAxis you could update them. Example of similar issue: http://jsfiddle.net/twmtezed/ Where should be label placed? Always at same coordinates or in the middle of visible part of a quadrant? What if there a quadrant is visible, but there is not enough space in it for a label?

Comment: I would like to always show the labels at the same coordinates. They do not need to be in the middle of the zoomedin quadrant. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the custom labels at the same coordinates you could use a scatter type series with enabled `dataLabels`, disabled mouse actions and hiden markers.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/t9jdkkvm/

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'scatter',
      zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    series: [{
      data: [
        [1, 0]
      ]
    }, {
      enableMouseTracking: false,
      linkedTo: 0,
      marker: {
        enabled: false
      },
      dataLabels: {
        defer: false,
        enabled: true,
        y: 20,
        style: {
            fontSize: '20px'
        },
        format: 'Qadrant {point.name}'
      },
      keys: ['x', 'y', 'name'],
      data: [
        [1, 1, 'A'],
        [-1, 1, 'B'],
        [-1, -1, 'C'],
        [1, -1, 'D']
      ]
    }],
    yAxis: {
      min: -2,
      max: 2
    },
    xAxis: {
      min: -2,
      max: 2
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help on this! Getting closer to what I need. Do you know how I can remove the bubbles for the labels? I have to use bubble style not scatter. Here is my updated code based on your advice [http://jsfiddle.net/ZLmU8/45/](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLmU8/45/)

Comment: @ek-ok Yes, you could set `minSize` and `maxSize` to `0` for that series - http://jsfiddle.net/ZLmU8/46/

Comment: Perfect! Last question, do you know why I loose bubble size with quadrant labels? http://jsfiddle.net/ZLmU8/51/.  Without labels bubbles show up with the correct z values. http://jsfiddle.net/ZLmU8/50/

Comment: @ek-ok Turns out that those bubbles will affect overall size range, so let's set color to 'none' and give all bubbles that should be only labels `z` value in range of actual bubbles - http://jsfiddle.net/ZLmU8/52/

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!